# trying to share a model in my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model

I am creating a website using a rails and I would like to share the model. I followed The tutorial for creating an article. In the ArticlesController is index, show, new, edit, create, update and destroy. I figured I would use this as the data entry part of my app. Then I was going to create a PageController that has home, news, videos, music and events. Here is my set up:

here is my Article model

```
 class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { large:"700x700>", medium:"300x300>", thumb:"150x150#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
    validates :title, presence: true,
                length: { minimum: 5 }
    belongs_to :page
end
```

here is my page model

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :article
end
```

here is my page controller

```
 class PageController < ApplicationController
  def home
 @page = Page.includes(:articles)
  end

  def news
  end

  def videos
  end

  def music
  end

  def events
  end
 end
```

here is my home view

```
<h1>Page#home</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/page/home.html.erb</p>


<%= @page.articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= article.title %>
  <%= article.content %>
  <%= article.image %>
<% end %>
```

here is the error I get

```
 undefined method `articles' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

not clear onwhats going on. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited information you posted, I am assuming the best thing for you to do is create an association. Pages should has_many articles and articles should belong_to a page. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

After that is setup, your controller can be set up as follows:

```
@page = Page.includes(:articles)
```

This will load your pages and its related articles in a single SQL query, then you can call

```
@page.articles.each |article|
  puts article.title
  puts article.content
  puts article.image 
end
```

You can now access all the information and use it as you please.